# Return array of matching string in javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays

```
let data = [{
    name: "John"
    school: ["def","abc"]     
}, 
{
    name: "Lily"
    school: "xyz"
}, {
    name: "Rose"
    school: "abc"
}]
```

I wanna return object which has school=="abc"`. i had try array.includes("abc). but it doesnt give expected output. it only return object which school that have only "abc" (output: Rose-abc). John should be included too

Comment: This is supposed to be an object, not an array.

Comment: its different array.

Comment: yeap..maybe i should called it object

Comment: Can you clarify your question? You have a collection of objects, and you want to return all objects which match a given condition on one of the properties (school)?

Comment: @mrukta Please edit your question. so that it can be more clear.

Comment: my point is, i want it to return obj that is school=abc. (In this case, to return arr1 & arr3)

Answer (score 4):

You could use

- [`Array#filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) for getting a new array with only some items of the array,
- [destructuring (assignment)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment) for getting only a single property of an object,
- a comparison with the wanted value, by checking if `school` is an array and if not make an array and take [`Array#includes`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes) for the check.
- This is the return value of the [arrow function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions).

```js
var array = [{ name: "John", school: ["def", "abc"] }, { name: "Lily", school: "xyz" }, { name: "Rose", school: "abc" }],
    result = array.filter(({ school }) => (Array.isArray(school) ? school : [school]).includes('abc'))

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: [object Object],[object Object]

Comment: as it looks like, you take the result directly, but this do not work. you need to read the item with the properties or have a look with `JSON.stringify`.

Answer (score 2):

```
arr = [{
    name: "John",
    school: "abc"
}, {
    name: "Lily",
    school: "xyz"
}, {
    name: "Rose",
    school: "abc"
}]


a = arr.filter((x) => {
        if (x.school == 'abc')
            return x
    })


console.log(a)
```

Comment: while working, leads it to a wrong assumption, you need to return the item, to get this item to the result set. the return value in the callback is evaluated and on this boolean value the item is retured or not.

Comment: it only return empty  object ===> [object Object],[object Object]

Comment: didn't get you.could you please put in some other words @NinaScholz

Comment: [`Array#filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) needs a return value, which is true or false or somethin which could be converted to a boolean value. to return an item could lead to a wrong result, if you have, for example zero as value, but if this value should in the filtered result set. in you case return just the result of the cpmparison without `if`: `return x.school == 'abc')`

Answer (score 1):

```
arr1 = [];
 var arr1= array1.concat(arr2);
 var index = arr1.findIndex(x => x.school== "abc");
    if ( index != -1 ){
    console.log(" found")
    }
```

first of all concat the array of two arrays and store arr1 
then find index of the arr1 which of that value abc if that value is not found 
it will return -1 based on this you can value is present or not

Comment: How does this answer the question?

Comment: hey first of all this answer is shorten 
first concat the array then
if you use findindex function means it will work

Comment: I have no problem with short answers when there is an explanation. However, a short answer consisting of incomplete code is going to confuse anyone who doesn't have enough programming experience to see what you were thinking.

Comment: hey i will improve my answers

Answer (score 1):

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/phvwqm70/12/)

```
var arr = [];
arr.push({ name: "John", school:"abc" });
arr.push({ name: "Lily", school:"xyz" });
arr.push({ name: "Rose", school:"abc" });

var temp = [];
arr.forEach(function(el) {
    if(el.school == "abc")
    temp.push(el);
});
console.log(temp);
```

Answer (score 0):

Say your array is like,

```
var arr=[ { name: "John" school:"abc" },
          { name: "Lily" school:"xyz" },
           { name: "Rose" school:"abc" }
        ]
```

then you can get the object like,

```
var item = arr.filter((obj)=>obj.school==="abc");
```

now, `item` will have the object you need

Comment: This only returns one match.

Comment: You can use, `filter` instead of 'find' to search for all occurances. But the OP has asked only for one object.

Comment: Very true, but the OP also thinks that anything which contains a string of characters === an array, so what they asked for isn't necessarily what they wanted.

Answer (score 0):

@mr ukta, if I'm understood correctly, it might help you.

```js
var students = [
 
  {
    name: "John",
    school:["abc", "def"]
 
  },
 
  {
    name: "John2",
    school:"Boom"
 
  },
  
 {
    name: "John3",
    school:"abc"
 
  },
 
];

var abcStudents = students.filter(({ school }) => (Array.isArray(school) ? school : [school]).includes('abc'))
console.log(abcStudents);
```

Comment: hii... i had tried it,, it only return empty  object ===> [object Object],[object Object]

Comment: @mrukta, could you please post your code, so that I can check, it seems like above code is working fine.

Comment: im just copied ur code and try running it at compiler. it give output  [object Object],[object Object]  @bharadwaja-gummadi